# Errors with CopyRequest and RewriteRequest in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to copy and move objects between buckets in Google Cloud Storage using the .NET API. As far as I can tell I am constructing the request correctly and I have verified that all the properties I am setting below are correct and what they should be but I get the following cryptic error:

```
Google.GoogleApiException : Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Required [400]
Errors [
    Message[Required] Location[ - ] Reason[required] Domain[global]
]
```

here is the code

```
Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object moveObj = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object() { Name = key, Size = (ulong)Length, ContentType = contentType };
ObjectsResource.RewriteRequest req = new ObjectsResource.RewriteRequest(_gcsClient, newObj,sourceBucket, key, destBucket, key);
req.Execute();
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out on my own, hopefully this answer will help you if you're having the same issue. Credit this the poorly written and inconsistent Cloud Storage API more than anything. Every other operation when you create a Storage 'Object' you specify the name for it (see first param):

```
new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object() { Name = key, Size = (ulong)Length, ContentType = contentType };
```

But for some reason this breaks when trying to move or copy the object so in this case you can omit it as you are passing the destinationKey as a property to the WriteRequest/CopyRequest anyway, so like this:

```
new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object() {Size = (ulong)Length, ContentType = contentType };
```